# What is the best tool to prevent write access to the root on a Debian computer that can be turned on with a command?

Tags: debian

I am on a Debian GNU/Linux, and i would like to be able to disable any write to the disk at some arbitrary time. It is ok, if i would need to reboot to re-enable the write access, but the best solution for me would be to not need to reboot to disable write. I also will need to have other mount points to be writable.

My question is: What approach is "State of the Art" for something like that currently? I would not want to be inventing a bicycle. Below are some of the possibilities, which i am examining, i am **not** asking to choose between them, if they are not the way to do what i am trying to; but hopefully this will clarify what i am after.

**lockfs**

It is provided by the `bilibop-lockfs` package has [mount.lockfs](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bilibop-lockfs/mount.lockfs.8.en.html) command, which claims to be able to do something similar, however "This script cannot be run manually, and fails if the root filesystem is not already managed by bilibop-lockfs." Which would require some very weird tricks to enable or disable it. In other words, it is probably not what i am looking for.

**ReadonlyRoot on Debian wiki**

A process described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot) requires changes to much of software installed on the machine, also seems to set up the situation, where readonly state will be the default, while writable state will be the exception, and that is not what i want.

**fsprotect**

Available [here](https://github.com/sharhalakis/fsprotect) would seem to allow me to do what i want. It will still force me to restart the computer in order to setup the read-only root system. As i understand, it will be possible to setup different menu options in Grub, one would turn on the use of `fsprotect` and the other would not, allowing to work as normal.

**overlayroot**

I was able to find it [for Ubuntu](https://pkgs.org/download/overlayroot), but not for Debian. Cannot find much information about it, except for the mention in the `blibop-lockfs` package ("This package can be used as an alternative to fsprotect or overlayroot").

**USE CASE**

*Note:* I believe that it will only distract somebody from being able to answer the question in the helpful manner, however, a polite request has been made, and i will satisfy the curiosity of the user who has asked. Please do **not** offer solutions to it, please **answer the question** that is actually stated, thank you.

I have software that i need to run, it may try to write to different parts of the file system. I require the protection from the alteration, the machine must be in the same state after the reboot after the loading of the software as it was before. The exception is that it does need to be able to write to the removable media.

Comment: As it is currently stated I don't see it as a security question. It is also not clear what is meant with "access to root" - the path "/" or the file system mounted on "/"? In the latter case - some systems have /home/* on the the same file system while others have these on separat file systems. Also, what should happen  when software is doing a write - fail (thus risking the software to malfunction) or preserve the semantics without writing to root fs (overlayfs)? To much unclear here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, the question was edited by another user, who has removed me stating that i am unsure whether it belongs on this SE. I can only find the phrase "access to root" in the title and your question, in the title it clearly states that it means write access, i can clarify that it means the write access to that whole partition and not only the directory. What should happen to the software? This depends upon what my options are, as with everything in the computer science "The user only knows what they want after they know what they can get." And hence my question about state of art.

Comment: *"What should happen to the software? This depends upon what my options are ..."* - To narrow down the options I think you need to explain the actual use case, not just the technical requirement (make root read only) you have. The options you've detailed are for very different use cases. And this question might be duplicate of [Remount a busy disk to read-only mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195010/remount-a-busy-disk-to-read-only-mode) at [unix.se].

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have added the use case (which will not be helpful, but still). Is your suggestion that this is a duplicate a camouflaged way to say that remountnig a busy disk to read-only mode is the state of the art of doing this? This is the solution, but it seems to me to be one of the worst ones... am i missing something?

Comment: What you have as use case sound more like you need sandboxing for the software which prevents or redirects writes. This is not the same as preventing write access to every other software. Note that it is not uncommon for software to write into /var/log (which might or might not be part of root fs), of course /home/$user but also /etc. And as for state of the art - it really depends on what you want to achieve. For your use case the state of the art is either sandboxing the specific software or having an architecture with a  read-only root.

Comment: Is the software potentially hostile and trying to work around the security controls that you would set up? Or is it just well-meaning but messy?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I do not expect anything which would actively try to break through any write protection (so nothing which would attempt to remount the partition or anything like that).

Comment: If you don't need to protect against anyone with root permission making changes, "remount in read-only mode" is probably the simplest solution. But as another comment already said, to help us give recommendations you must describe your use case.